# Why does Lenstra ECM work?

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, elliptic-curves, factoring

I came across Lenstra ECM algorithm and I wonder why it works.
Please refer for simplicity to Wikipedia section [Why does the algorithm work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization#Why_does_the_algorithm_work.3F)

I NOT a math expert but I understood first part well enough (I suppose), what I miss is

> When this is the case, $kP$ does not exist on the original curve, and in the computations we found some $v$ with either $\text{gcd}(v,p)=p$ or $\text{gcd}(v,q)=q$, but not both. That is, $\text{gcd}(v,n)$ gave a non-trivial factor of $n$.

As far as I know this has to do with the fact that $E(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$ is not a group if $n$ is not prime so some element (i.e. $x_1-x_2$) is not invertible but what is the link between non invertible elements and $n$ factors?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Have you studied or worked with some of the simpler factoring methods like [Pollard's rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm)?  It would help to have some clearer idea of your math background, e.g. understanding of elementary number theory.

Comment: Yes, I studied Pollard's Rho (with Pollard p-1 and William p+1)

Comment: I'm fond of David Bressoud's book, **Factorization and Primality Testing**.  If you are interested in arithmetic of elliptic curves, then another favorite is Silverman and Tate's **Rational Points on Elliptic Curves**.  You can look for reviews, etc. in Google Books or at bookseller websites.

Answer (score -2):

Read this [paper.](http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/papers/40760525.pdf)

[image]

this is just a piece of hole paper.